# Dataloader Batch Mode Extract CLI Process.bat Error

Tags: batch, data-loader, error, error-messages

I am trying to do an extract via the CLI of dataloader and getting an error when I run my process.bat.

Here is error message when running process.bat on csvAccountExtractProcess in the process-conf file:[image]

Below is my process-conf.xml file:
[image]

SOQL statement that got cutoff:

select id, name, owner.termination_date__c, owner.profile.name, owner.name, owner.managerid, owner.userrole.name from account where owner.termination_date__c <= today and owner.userrole.name like 'wws%' and owner.isactive = false

I'm not sure if my directories are setup correctly so including quick structure view:

System (C:)

```
  -Data Loader
        -bin
        -Java
        -licenses
        -samples
        -target
        -conf                   
             -data
                 -accountExtract.csv
             -sdl
                 -termed_user_infoExtractMap.sdl
             -status
                 -accountMasterSoapTrace.log
                 -error0413060133.csv
                 -success0413060133.csv
             -database-conf.xml
             -dataloader-33.0.0-uber.jar
             -key.txt
             -process-conf.xml
```

If any additional info is required, please do not hesitate to let me know.  I really appreciate the help!  Thanks!

Comment: it generates log files when cli is run. please check the same for more detailed error message.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the **dataloader-33.0.0-uber.jar** to be in **Data Loader/** folder and it should work fine.